# gmake with subdirectories

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a makefile that works with pmake, but not GNU make. I am just moving it from a trivial makefile to a bit more complex, the issue cropped up with making the src and include directores.

I can't use GNU make specific syntax, it needs to be portable.

The issue is that .c.o is never dealt with, so the .c files are never compiled to .o.

```
gcc -o hello main.o display.o  
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find main.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find display.o: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile4:13: hello] Error 1
```

The makefile looks like this:

```
.SUFFIXES:

OBJECTS=main.o display.o
BINARY=hello
CC=gcc
CFLAGS_ALL=$(CFLAGS) -Iinclude -std=c17 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic

.PHONY: all
all: $(BINARY)

hello: $(OBJECTS)
        $(CC) -o $(BINARY) $(OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBRARIES)

main.o: src/main.c include/display.h
display.o: src/display.c include/display.h

.SUFFIXES: .o .c

.c.o:
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS_ALL) -o $@ -c $<

.PHONY: clean
clean:
        rm -rf $(OBJECTS) $(BINARY) $(DOCS)
```

Any thoughts on the syntax that will convince GNU make to work, while still having pmake work?

The output with -d is:

```
GNU Make 4.3
Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 1988-2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Reading makefiles...
Reading makefile 'makefile4'...
Updating makefiles....
 Considering target file 'makefile4'.
  Looking for an implicit rule for 'makefile4'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'makefile4'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite 'makefile4.o'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'makefile4'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite 'makefile4.c'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'makefile4'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite 'makefile4,v'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'makefile4'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/makefile4,v'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'makefile4'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/makefile4'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'makefile4'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite 's.makefile4'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'makefile4'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite 'SCCS/s.makefile4'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'makefile4'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite 'makefile4.o'.
  Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'makefile4.o'.
   Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'makefile4'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'makefile4.c'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'makefile4.o'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'makefile4.o,v'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'makefile4.o'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/makefile4.o,v'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'makefile4.o'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/makefile4.o'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'makefile4.o'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 's.makefile4.o'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'makefile4.o'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'SCCS/s.makefile4.o'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'makefile4'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'makefile4.c'.
   Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'makefile4.c'.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'makefile4'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'makefile4.w'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'makefile4.c'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'makefile4.c,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'makefile4.c'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/makefile4.c,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'makefile4.c'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/makefile4.c'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'makefile4.c'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 's.makefile4.c'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'makefile4.c'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'SCCS/s.makefile4.c'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'makefile4'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite 'makefile4.w'.
    Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'makefile4.w'.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'makefile4.w'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'makefile4.w,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'makefile4.w'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/makefile4.w,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'makefile4.w'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/makefile4.w'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'makefile4.w'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 's.makefile4.w'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'makefile4.w'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'SCCS/s.makefile4.w'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'makefile4'.
  Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite 'makefile4.c'.
  No implicit rule found for 'makefile4'.
  Finished prerequisites of target file 'makefile4'.
 No need to remake target 'makefile4'.
Updating goal targets....
Considering target file 'all'.
 File 'all' does not exist.
  Considering target file 'hello'.
   File 'hello' does not exist.
    Considering target file 'main.o'.
     File 'main.o' does not exist.
     Looking for an implicit rule for 'main.o'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'main'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'main.c'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'main.o'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'main.o,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'main.o'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/main.o,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'main.o'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/main.o'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'main.o'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 's.main.o'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'main.o'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'SCCS/s.main.o'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'main'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'main.c'.
     Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'main.c'.
      Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
      Trying pattern rule with stem 'main'.
      Trying implicit prerequisite 'main.w'.
      Trying pattern rule with stem 'main.c'.
      Trying implicit prerequisite 'main.c,v'.
      Trying pattern rule with stem 'main.c'.
      Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/main.c,v'.
      Trying pattern rule with stem 'main.c'.
      Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/main.c'.
      Trying pattern rule with stem 'main.c'.
      Trying implicit prerequisite 's.main.c'.
      Trying pattern rule with stem 'main.c'.
      Trying implicit prerequisite 'SCCS/s.main.c'.
      Trying pattern rule with stem 'main'.
      Trying implicit prerequisite 'main.w'.
      Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'main.w'.
       Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
       Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
       Trying pattern rule with stem 'main.w'.
       Trying implicit prerequisite 'main.w,v'.
       Trying pattern rule with stem 'main.w'.
       Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/main.w,v'.
       Trying pattern rule with stem 'main.w'.
       Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/main.w'.
       Trying pattern rule with stem 'main.w'.
       Trying implicit prerequisite 's.main.w'.
       Trying pattern rule with stem 'main.w'.
       Trying implicit prerequisite 'SCCS/s.main.w'.
     No implicit rule found for 'main.o'.
      Considering target file 'src/main.c'.
       Looking for an implicit rule for 'src/main.c'.
       Trying pattern rule with stem 'main'.
       Trying implicit prerequisite 'src/main.w'.
       Trying pattern rule with stem 'main.c'.
       Trying implicit prerequisite 'src/main.c,v'.
       Trying pattern rule with stem 'main.c'.
       Trying implicit prerequisite 'src/RCS/main.c,v'.
       Trying pattern rule with stem 'main.c'.
       Trying implicit prerequisite 'src/RCS/main.c'.
       Trying pattern rule with stem 'main.c'.
       Trying implicit prerequisite 'src/s.main.c'.
       Trying pattern rule with stem 'main.c'.
       Trying implicit prerequisite 'src/SCCS/s.main.c'.
       Trying pattern rule with stem 'main'.
       Trying implicit prerequisite 'src/main.w'.
       Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'src/main.w'.
        Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
        Trying pattern rule with stem 'main.w'.
        Trying implicit prerequisite 'src/main.w,v'.
        Trying pattern rule with stem 'main.w'.
        Trying implicit prerequisite 'src/RCS/main.w,v'.
        Trying pattern rule with stem 'main.w'.
        Trying implicit prerequisite 'src/RCS/main.w'.
        Trying pattern rule with stem 'main.w'.
        Trying implicit prerequisite 'src/s.main.w'.
        Trying pattern rule with stem 'main.w'.
        Trying implicit prerequisite 'src/SCCS/s.main.w'.
       No implicit rule found for 'src/main.c'.
       Finished prerequisites of target file 'src/main.c'.
      No need to remake target 'src/main.c'.
      Considering target file 'include/display.h'.
       Looking for an implicit rule for 'include/display.h'.
       Trying pattern rule with stem 'display.h'.
       Trying implicit prerequisite 'include/display.h.o'.
       Trying pattern rule with stem 'display.h'.
       Trying implicit prerequisite 'include/display.h.c'.
       Trying pattern rule with stem 'display.h'.
       Trying implicit prerequisite 'include/display.h,v'.
       Trying pattern rule with stem 'display.h'.
       Trying implicit prerequisite 'include/RCS/display.h,v'.
       Trying pattern rule with stem 'display.h'.
       Trying implicit prerequisite 'include/RCS/display.h'.
       Trying pattern rule with stem 'display.h'.
       Trying implicit prerequisite 'include/s.display.h'.
       Trying pattern rule with stem 'display.h'.
       Trying implicit prerequisite 'include/SCCS/s.display.h'.
       Trying pattern rule with stem 'display.h'.
       Trying implicit prerequisite 'include/display.h.o'.
       Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'include/display.h.o'.
        Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
        Trying pattern rule with stem 'display.h'.
        Trying implicit prerequisite 'include/display.h.c'.
        Trying pattern rule with stem 'display.h.o'.
        Trying implicit prerequisite 'include/display.h.o,v'.
        Trying pattern rule with stem 'display.h.o'.
        Trying implicit prerequisite 'include/RCS/display.h.o,v'.
        Trying pattern rule with stem 'display.h.o'.
        Trying implicit prerequisite 'include/RCS/display.h.o'.
        Trying pattern rule with stem 'display.h.o'.
        Trying implicit prerequisite 'include/s.display.h.o'.
        Trying pattern rule with stem 'display.h.o'.
        Trying implicit prerequisite 'include/SCCS/s.display.h.o'.
        Trying pattern rule with stem 'display.h'.
        Trying implicit prerequisite 'include/display.h.c'.
        Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'include/display.h.c'.
         Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
         Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
         Trying pattern rule with stem 'display.h'.
         Trying implicit prerequisite 'include/display.h.w'.
         Trying pattern rule with stem 'display.h.c'.
         Trying implicit prerequisite 'include/display.h.c,v'.
         Trying pattern rule with stem 'display.h.c'.
         Trying implicit prerequisite 'include/RCS/display.h.c,v'.
         Trying pattern rule with stem 'display.h.c'.
         Trying implicit prerequisite 'include/RCS/display.h.c'.
         Trying pattern rule with stem 'display.h.c'.
         Trying implicit prerequisite 'include/s.display.h.c'.
         Trying pattern rule with stem 'display.h.c'.
         Trying implicit prerequisite 'include/SCCS/s.display.h.c'.
         Trying pattern rule with stem 'display.h'.
         Trying implicit prerequisite 'include/display.h.w'.
         Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'include/display.h.w'.
          Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
          Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
          Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
          Trying pattern rule with stem 'display.h.w'.
          Trying implicit prerequisite 'include/display.h.w,v'.
          Trying pattern rule with stem 'display.h.w'.
          Trying implicit prerequisite 'include/RCS/display.h.w,v'.
          Trying pattern rule with stem 'display.h.w'.
          Trying implicit prerequisite 'include/RCS/display.h.w'.
          Trying pattern rule with stem 'display.h.w'.
          Trying implicit prerequisite 'include/s.display.h.w'.
          Trying pattern rule with stem 'display.h.w'.
          Trying implicit prerequisite 'include/SCCS/s.display.h.w'.
       Trying pattern rule with stem 'display.h'.
       Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite 'include/display.h.c'.
       No implicit rule found for 'include/display.h'.
       Finished prerequisites of target file 'include/display.h'.
      No need to remake target 'include/display.h'.
     Finished prerequisites of target file 'main.o'.
    Must remake target 'main.o'.
    Successfully remade target file 'main.o'.
    Considering target file 'display.o'.
     File 'display.o' does not exist.
     Looking for an implicit rule for 'display.o'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'display'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'display.c'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'display.o'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'display.o,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'display.o'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/display.o,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'display.o'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/display.o'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'display.o'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 's.display.o'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'display.o'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'SCCS/s.display.o'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'display'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite 'display.c'.
     Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'display.c'.
      Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
      Trying pattern rule with stem 'display'.
      Trying implicit prerequisite 'display.w'.
      Trying pattern rule with stem 'display.c'.
      Trying implicit prerequisite 'display.c,v'.
      Trying pattern rule with stem 'display.c'.
      Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/display.c,v'.
      Trying pattern rule with stem 'display.c'.
      Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/display.c'.
      Trying pattern rule with stem 'display.c'.
      Trying implicit prerequisite 's.display.c'.
      Trying pattern rule with stem 'display.c'.
      Trying implicit prerequisite 'SCCS/s.display.c'.
      Trying pattern rule with stem 'display'.
      Trying implicit prerequisite 'display.w'.
      Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'display.w'.
       Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
       Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
       Trying pattern rule with stem 'display.w'.
       Trying implicit prerequisite 'display.w,v'.
       Trying pattern rule with stem 'display.w'.
       Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/display.w,v'.
       Trying pattern rule with stem 'display.w'.
       Trying implicit prerequisite 'RCS/display.w'.
       Trying pattern rule with stem 'display.w'.
       Trying implicit prerequisite 's.display.w'.
       Trying pattern rule with stem 'display.w'.
       Trying implicit prerequisite 'SCCS/s.display.w'.
     No implicit rule found for 'display.o'.
      Considering target file 'src/display.c'.
       Looking for an implicit rule for 'src/display.c'.
       Trying pattern rule with stem 'display'.
       Trying implicit prerequisite 'src/display.w'.
       Trying pattern rule with stem 'display.c'.
       Trying implicit prerequisite 'src/display.c,v'.
       Trying pattern rule with stem 'display.c'.
       Trying implicit prerequisite 'src/RCS/display.c,v'.
       Trying pattern rule with stem 'display.c'.
       Trying implicit prerequisite 'src/RCS/display.c'.
       Trying pattern rule with stem 'display.c'.
       Trying implicit prerequisite 'src/s.display.c'.
       Trying pattern rule with stem 'display.c'.
       Trying implicit prerequisite 'src/SCCS/s.display.c'.
       Trying pattern rule with stem 'display'.
       Trying implicit prerequisite 'src/display.w'.
       Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'src/display.w'.
        Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
        Trying pattern rule with stem 'display.w'.
        Trying implicit prerequisite 'src/display.w,v'.
        Trying pattern rule with stem 'display.w'.
        Trying implicit prerequisite 'src/RCS/display.w,v'.
        Trying pattern rule with stem 'display.w'.
        Trying implicit prerequisite 'src/RCS/display.w'.
        Trying pattern rule with stem 'display.w'.
        Trying implicit prerequisite 'src/s.display.w'.
        Trying pattern rule with stem 'display.w'.
        Trying implicit prerequisite 'src/SCCS/s.display.w'.
       No implicit rule found for 'src/display.c'.
       Finished prerequisites of target file 'src/display.c'.
      No need to remake target 'src/display.c'.
      Pruning file 'include/display.h'.
     Finished prerequisites of target file 'display.o'.
    Must remake target 'display.o'.
    Successfully remade target file 'display.o'.
   Finished prerequisites of target file 'hello'.
  Must remake target 'hello'.
gcc -o hello main.o display.o  
Putting child 0x55f5c3999ea0 (hello) PID 167980 on the chain.
Live child 0x55f5c3999ea0 (hello) PID 167980 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find main.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find display.o: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Reaping losing child 0x55f5c3999ea0 PID 167980 
make: *** [makefile4:15: hello] Error 1
Removing child 0x55f5c3999ea0 PID 167980 from chain.
```

Comment: The backticks before the `.PHONY` rule look wrong to me but they shouldn't cause problems.  There's nothing wrong with this makefile that I can see, so either you copied and pasted it incorrectly or there's something weird about your system that you haven't described.  I recommend running GNU make with the `-d` option and see what it has to say about the files `main.o` and `display.o`.  Warning: the output is voluminous.  You may want to redirect it to a file.

Comment: oops the ``` was me dealing with the markdown, SO has changes since I last posted a question :-) yes, just copy/paste -d was not useful, sadly.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "not useful".  It will tell you exactly what make considered.  Why did make say that it didn't rebuild the `main.o` file (for example)?

Comment: @MadScientist updated with the -d output, also added an answer with a workaround that I don't like.

Comment: I am a bit surprised that this works with `pmake` (but I do not know `pmake`). If, with this Makefile, `pmake` is capable of discovering that `main.o` can be obtained by compiling `src/main.c`, I am afraid this is not a portable feature anyway. POSIX says: _If the .s1 suffix is found in .SUFFIXES, the inference rules shall be searched in the order defined for the first .s2.s1 rule whose prerequisite file ($*.s2) exists_. In your case there is no `main.c` so your `.c.o` suffix rule shall not be considered to build `main.o`...

Comment: The `gmake -d` output is also surprising: `Successfully remade target file 'main.o'.` and `Successfully remade target file 'display.o'.` are quite strange. Could it be a bug in GNU Make 4.3?

Comment: Sorry, I somehow missed that your source files were in different directories than the object files.  It's not possible to use traditional POSIX standard suffix rules and put targets in different directories from the prerequisite.  It's not supported.  If you can't use non-standard features you have two choices: either put the object files into the same directory as the source files, or write explicit rules for each target and don't use suffix rules.

Comment: I'll just back them out of the src dir for now, it was a step in getting to cmake anyways. Thanks! @MadScientist

Answer (score 0):

My unhappy solution is:

```
OBJECTS=$(SRC)/main.o $(SRC)/display.o
```